# $browser.cookies is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm doing unit test based on angular 1.3.15 with Karma and jasmine. In my unit test, I inject $rootScope and run `$rootScope.$digest()`, then I got such error which alerts: `browser.cookies is not a function`. Is it an angular bug or did I missed something?

Comment: did you include the angular-mocks folder in your karma config file?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using angular 1.3.15 with angular-mocks 1.4.x, as I downgraded it to 1.3.x, it's solved.

Comment: Upgrading Angular to 1.4.x also fixed it for me.

Comment: note: it is the angular-mocks module that needed to be downgraded to 1.3.x